# Does $||x||\leq ||\overline{x}||$ and $||y||\leq ||\overline{y}||$ imply $||x-y||\leq ||\overline{x}-\overline{y}||$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I've been working with norms for quite a bit now, and I have started to ponder whether

$$||x||\leq ||\overline{x}||\text{ and }||y||\leq ||\overline{y}||\Rightarrow||x-y||\leq ||\overline{x}-\overline{y}||?$$

I can't seem to be able to verify whether this is true or not so I was wondering if anyone can help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if $x=\overline x=\overline y$ but $y=-x$?

Comment: Does the $\overline{x}$ notation indicate a complex conjugate?

Answer (score 2):

That's not even true for numbers: $|1|\leq|2|$, $|2|\leq|2|$, $|1-2|\not\leq|2-2|$.

Comment: If $x=1$, shouldn't your first inequality be $|1|\leq |1|$? In which case the latter will be true.

Comment: Why? What's $\bar x$ for you?

Comment: A complex conjugate. In which case $\|x\|=\|\overline{x}\|$. This is why I am confused by this question.

Comment: And you would have $\|x-y\|=\|\bar x-\bar y\|$, so the question would make absolutely no sense. And the question does not mention complex numbers at all, and it does mention a *norm*. What would make you think this is about complex numbers?

Comment: The notation used. It's common to associate $\overline{x}$ with a complex conjugate.